# Understanding Event Handlers in lync

Tags: c#, lync, lync-client-sdk

im very new to C# as well as lync SDK, can sumone help me to understand the meaning of the below line.
what i understood was whenever lefthand side event occures it will call the rightthand side handler. am i correct?

```
lyncClient.ConversationManager.ConversationAdded += ConversationManager_ConversationAdded;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add an event handler called `ConversationManager_ConversationAdded` to a structure associated with event `ConversationAdded`. When a `ConversationAdded` event occurs, all handlers added will be called with arguments defining context of this event occurence.

Comment: thanks :) .i have seen many sample code where the ConversationManager_ConversationAdded event handler is having 2 arguments. these arguments are sent by default?

Comment: yes those arguments will be provided to your event handler when it is called, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: They are here to provide you context of event call - first one contains the object sender (in this case `lyncClient.ConversationManager`); the one (unless it's plain `System.EventArgs`) could carry some additional information.